# startup script on GCP instance fails at wget

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Does anyone know what the issue might be?  Seems similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240477/ec2-startup-script-gets-stuck-on-wget) on AWS.  [This guy](http://scottsfarley.com/research/cloudcomputing/2016/06/05/Startup-and-Shutdown-Scripts-GCE.html) seems to run wget without failure on GCP but my script provided below fails.  It is not unique to wget for this python link.  It fails on wget for every url I've ever tried.

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get --yes install build-essential
apt-get --yes install make
apt-get --yes install git
apt-get install unzip
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ~/Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

**EDITED** after Mohit's suggestion:

second from the last line needed to be changed to

```
bash ./Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda
```

then upon SSH-ing into the instance

```
cd /
export PATH="/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

to set Anaconda as the default python to use

Comment: can you put the cloudinit logs here?

Comment: @MohitKumar the information from Logging -> Logs pane does not show an error anywhere.  Are you referring to something specific?  The logs are quite long to post here.

Comment: Checkout the logs here. 
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
/var/log/cloud-init.log

Comment: head: cannot open '/var/log/cloud-init-output.log' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open '/var/log/cloud-init.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: I am sorry, thats for AWS. Can you check this location '/var/log/startupscript.log' ? 
Ref: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: From your recommendation I located the log files and saw that the script was not failing on the wget.  I just needed to pay more attention to the relative paths.

Comment: are you able to solve your issue?

Comment: yes, the relative paths I originally used were wrong.  The problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to instasll wget:

```
sudo apt-get install wget -y
```

To check startup script output in debian os, run:

```
cat /var/log/daemon.log | less
```