# Startup on Google Cloud fails at wget

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, wget

I have the following startup script in Google Cloud Compute Engine:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
sudo pip3 install pymysql
sudo pip3 install sympy
wget [DOMAIN]/file.tar.gz ~/file.tar.gz
tar -vzxf ~/file.tar.gz ~/
```

But when I log in, neither the tar or the files within it are in the home folder. I have tried various permutations including `cd ~` before, or giving an absolute reference `/home/[username]/` in the script, but nothing seems to work.

I have seen this:
[startup script on GCP instance fails at wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841616/startup-script-on-gcp-instance-fails-at-wget#)

But as I am not executing a bash file, I don't think the syntax still applies?

Comment: Hi @Luke Richards, apologies if this is stating the obvious, but have tried SSH-ing into the instance and checked the daemon.log file to confirm that the boot script is running, and to see whether there are any messages in there that might give you a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have connection to the server and that your local firewall is not blocking the traffic.

Check that you have the permissions to download the file from [DOMAIN].

wget might get disconnected during the download but you can use options described in this [documentation](http://www.editcorp.com/personal/lars_appel/wget/v1/wget_7.html) that will help you make the download successful, like the -t and -c options for trying the download more times or continue getting a partially-downloaded file, respectively.